# How use filter or search in angularjs with md-virtual-repeat?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I don't know syntax filter or search with md-virtual-repeat, help me, thank you very much!!!

```html
<input type="text" ng-model="searchId"> <!-- old: model="searchId" -->

<md-virtual-repeat-container>
  <div md-virtual-repeat="i in items | filter:{searchId}">
    <div>{{i.id}}</div>
    <div>{{i.name}}</div>
  </div>
</md-virtual-repeat-container>
```

```js
iteams array object in Javascript, I'm done!
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: You need to change model to ng-model & then need to change {searchId} to searchId.
I have created a simple demo for you. please look at it.

```js
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'John'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Steve'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Joey'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'Mary'
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: 'Marylin'
    }
  ];
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp'>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchId">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter:
  searchId">
          <td>{{item.id}}</td>
          <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, ng-repeat is work but md-virtual-repeat is not, why? Can you help me?

Comment: please create a snippet for that. I will resolve your all issues here

Comment: <tr md-virtual-repeat="item in items | filter:
  searchId">  is not work, can items loop not work with filter

Comment: This does not address using a filter with md-virtual-repeat. You are using native ng-repeat.

Comment: @lyly, I am partially agree with @tbone849. You have to use native `ng-repeat` with filter that you want to apply on particular data. this created in native angular directive.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove {} in filter

```
<input type="text" model="searchId">

<md-virtual-repeat-container>
  <div md-virtual-repeat="i in items | filter:searchId">
     <div>{{i.id}}</div>
     <div>{{i.name}}</div>
  </div>
</md-virtual-repeat-container>
```